# How to get corrected residuals from nlme::gls model with AR1 structure in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, autoregressive, generalized-least-squares

I am new to time series analysis. I am trying to use nlme::gls to add an AR1 structure to a regression model. I'd like to look at the autocorrelation of the residuals with and without this structure applied. However, the residuals() function appears to give *uncorrected* residuals (ie., before applying to the AR1 structure). How can I generate the corrected residuals? MWE is below.

```
set.seed(1)
x<-seq(0,20,.1)
y<-rbinom(201,1,.5)
z<-sin(x)*3+y+rnorm(201,0,1)

mdl_lm<-gls(z~y)
summary(mdl_lm)
acf(residuals(mdl_lm))

mdl_AR1<-gls(z~y,correlation = corAR1())
summary(mdl_AR1)
acf(residuals(mdl_AR1)) # This returns the same plot
```

Comment: Study `help("residuals.gls")`. You want the normalized residuals: `acf(residuals(mdl_AR1, type = "normalized"))`

Comment: Thank you @Roland! That works great.